# How To display Hello World using *x

Tags: c

How do I display everything in the `char *` `x`?

```
int main() {
    char *x = "HELLO WORLD";
    printf("%c", *x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you need to use a loop, such as `while` or `for`.

Comment: it is iterable. So you can loop over it.

Comment: `printf("%s",x);`, but this this answer should have been found with a google search.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a pointer to a null terminated array of `char`, aka a C string:

- as coded, you only pass the first character `H` and output this single character with `"%c"`. The behavior is defined but not what you want.
- to print the C string with `printf`, you would use `"%s"` and pass `x` as an extra argument.
- you also need to include `<stdio.h>`
- you should also output a trailing newline, for example by using `"%s\n"`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *x = "HELLO WORLD";
    printf("%s\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "x" is already a pointer and the '%s' output format specifier expects a pointer to a char array that is NUL terminated. Therefore, the following will work nicely.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *x = "HELLO WORLD";
    printf( "%s\n", x );
    return 0;
}
```

or, if you want to display the char array, one character at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *x = "HELLO WORLD";
    for( char *y = x; *y; y++ )
    {
        printf( "%c", y );
    }
    printf( "\n" );  // or puts( "" );
    return 0;
}
```

note the '\n' is so the data is immediately output to the terminal, rather than sitting in the `stdout` buffer until the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

Format specifier `%c` is used to print one character at a time
use `%s` (string specifier) to print a string in C (it must be null terminated) this link will explain C format specifiers
[link](https://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html)